# Is it possible to use ES6 syntax on require() property?

Tags: ecmascript-6

Is it possible to use ES6 import instead of require?

```
var Promise = require('es6-promise').Promise;
```

Comment: Have you already test ? Any error ?

Comment: Did you search? [`[ecmascript-6] require to import`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Becmascript-6%5D+require+to+import)

Comment: `import` means using ES6. ES6 means having `Promise` built in, so the example doesn't make sense.

Comment: @zeroflagL say about it browsers that don't have Promise support. This is polyfill usage example.

Comment: @FelixKling thx, exactly what I need